# How to wait till PouchDB successfully connects

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am using pouchdb at client side(ionic mobile app) couchdb at server side.

I need to perform operation after pouchdb successfully created and sync with couchdb.

so how can I wait till pouchdb complete initial activity.then after only my client side execution should start.

currently pouch is working on asynchronous manner so sometime before pouch initialize my application starts execution and I am getting error for pouchdb.

Comment: have you tried using a .then. so say you have $scope.connect = function(){
var req = {options};
$http(req).success(callback).error(callback).then(callback)
}

The .then callback function will not run until after all the data is successfully back and success and error have run. Check this out for more info http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Comment: Thanks jess,okay then i need to put all code in then block which i want to execute after pouchdb connects. right?

Comment: yep, should work. Here is a example.
db.get('mittens').then(function (doc) {
  // okay, doc contains our document
}).catch(function (err) {
  // oh noes! we got an error
});

Comment: Similar to angular it uses a promise system. You can read more about it here. http://pouchdb.com/guides/async-code.html

Comment: Hope it works out. I use this method with mongodb but i think it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with asynchronous functions such as waiting for a respone from a server in JavaScript you use promises or callbacks to wait for an answer.

from the [pouchdb docs](http://pouchdb.com/guides/async-code.html) we can read that they provide a fully asynchronous API.

**Callback** version:

```
db.get('mittens', function (error, doc) {
  if (error) {
    // oh noes! we got an error
  } else {
    // okay, doc contains our document
  }
});
```

**Promise** version:

```
db.get('mittens').then(function (doc) {
  // okay, doc contains our document
}).catch(function (err) {
  // oh noes! we got an error
});
```